# можно ли в инлайн кнопке создать функцию?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Вопрос. Можно ли в инлайн кнопке создать функцию ? При этом что бы она выполнялась . Телеграмм бот. Библиотека Телеграмм бот айпи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Инлайн-кнопки. Что это такое? Это специальные объекты, которые "цепляются" к конкретным сообщениям и распространяют своё действие, в общем случае, только на них. Делятся такие кнопки на три типа: URL-кнопки, Callback-кнопки и Switch-кнопки.
Самыми простыми являются кнопки-ссылки (URL). Как видно из названия, их цель - просто перекидывать пользователей по определенным веб-адресам.
Переход по ссылке:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def default_test(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    url_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Перейти на Google", url="https://google.com")
    keyboard.add(url_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку и перейди в поисковик.", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Callback-кнопки позволяют выполнять произвольные действия по их нажатию. Всё зависит от того, какие параметры каждая кнопка в себе несёт. Соответственно, все нажатия будут приводить к отправке боту объекта CallbackQuery, содержащему поле data, в котором написана некоторая строка, заложенная в кнопку, а также либо объект Message, если сообщение отправлено ботом в обычном режиме, либо поле inline_message_id, если сообщение отправлено в inline-режиме.

```
# Обычный режим
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def any_msg(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    callback_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нажми меня", callback_data="test")
    keyboard.add(callback_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Сообщение из обычного режима", reply_markup=keyboard)


# Inline-режим с непустым запросом
@bot.inline_handler(lambda query: len(query.query) > 0)
def query_text(query):
    kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    # Добавляем callback-кнопку с содержимым "test"
    kb.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нажми меня", callback_data="test"))
    results = []
    single_msg = types.InlineQueryResultArticle(
        id="1", title="Press me",
        input_message_content=types.InputTextMessageContent(message_text="Cообщение из inline-режима"),
        reply_markup=kb
    )
    results.append(single_msg)
    bot.answer_inline_query(query.id, results)


# В большинстве случаев целесообразно разбить этот хэндлер на несколько маленьких
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    # Если сообщение из чата с ботом
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "test":
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="chat")
    # Если сообщение из инлайн-режима
    elif call.inline_message_id:
        if call.data == "test":
            bot.edit_message_text(inline_message_id=call.inline_message_id, text="inline")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

последний тип кнопок - Switch (переключатель). Они нужны, чаще всего, для обучения пользователей работе с ботом в inline-режиме. Чтобы активировать сделать кнопку такого типа, нужно указать аргумент switch_inline_query либо пустой, либо с каким-либо текстом. В последнем случае этот текст будет сразу подставлен в поле ввода, например, для показа демонстрации inline. Как вообще работает такая кнопка? При нажатии на неё Telegram предложит выбрать чат, после чего подставит в поле ввода ник вашего бота и (если есть), текст, указанный вами в аргументе switch_inline_query.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def any_msg(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    switch_button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нажми меня", switch_inline_query="Telegram")
    keyboard.add(switch_button)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Cообщение из обычного режима", reply_markup=keyboard)
```

А вообще почитайте вот эти уроки - [mastergroosha](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial/) и с библиотекой [aiogram](https://surik00.gitbooks.io/aiogram-lessons/content/)